# How to use visibleProperty.bind

Tags: java, javafx, object-property

I would like to know if this is the way I should use visibleProperty :

```
property.visibleProperty().bind(anotherProperty.isEqualTo(anObject))
```

and if this is the way, does the isEqualTo compare the objet with the value of the 'anotherProperty' or the anotherProperty itself ? Because I need the first option but I don't know how to achieve it.

Thanks !

Comment: Depends on what you're trying to achieve. If `property` is a `Node` and you want keep it visible iff the value of `anotherProperty` is equal to `anObject` (or the value of `anObject`, if it's a suitable property itself), it seems to be correct.

Comment: Okay thanks I was afraid the comparison would be between the property itself and the object which would be never true

Comment: Should be simple to check. Simply set up a UI with some node to display/hide and a `TextField` and use the `text` property of the `TextField` in the binding compating it to some literal string (or the `text` property of another `TextField`).